# How to compute the arrival rate

Tags: queueing-theory

I have a data set of interarrivals . I need to compute the arrival rate.

Should I compute the mean interarrival and then inverse it to get the arrival rate ? or should I inverse all the interarrivals and then compute the mean to get the mean arrival rate.

Comment: You could just divide the number of arrivals by the sum of times between the arrivals, provided the interarrival times do not overlap.

Comment: My question is , should the mean arrival rate be the mean of the instantaneous arrival rates ?  , Because the mean of the inverses is not the inverse of the mean .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following example:

[image]

For the calculation of the arrival rate, the first arrival is not taken into account, because it serves as baseline. The times and interarrival times do only tell something about the arrivals after the first one.